# Is a tree with a single node sorted?

Tags: sorting, tree, nodes

A stupid question, but is a tree with a single node sorted? In particular, does it matter which kind of sort is in question? Like inorder, preorder, etc. For example, is 5 sorted?

Comment: Obviously :). Any container with a single object is sorted by definition.

Comment: Also, the traversals are just the order in which you visit the nodes. The only one that would return a "sorted" result of a container of natural numbers (1,2,...n) would be in-order.

Comment: Ditto for the empty tree, which, if asked that way, might have generated some silly comments about empty trees falling, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the formal definition of sorted order is the following: an array of n elements is sorted if for every i and j between 1 and n inclusive, if i < j, then A[i] < A[j]. If n = 0 or n = 1, then this statement is [vacuously true](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth) because there is no way to choose an i and a j in the range such that i < j. As a result, any empty list, and any list of just one element, is sorted.